# Forced to use of Mutex when it's not required

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

I am writing a game and have a player list defined as follows:

```
pub struct PlayerList {
    by_name: HashMap<String, Arc<Mutex<Player>>>,
    by_uuid: HashMap<Uuid, Arc<Mutex<Player>>>,
}
```

This struct has methods for adding, removing, getting players, and getting the player count.

The `NetworkServer` and `Server` shares this list as follows:

```
NetworkServer {
    ...
    player_list: Arc<Mutex<PlayerList>>,
    ...
}

Server {
    ...
    player_list: Arc<Mutex<PlayerList>>,
    ...
}
```

This is inside an `Arc<Mutex>` because the `NetworkServer` accesses the list in a different thread (network loop).
When a player joins, a thread is spawned for them and they are added to the player_list.

Although the only operation I'm doing is adding to `player_list`, I'm forced to use `Arc<Mutex<Player>>` instead of the more natural `Rc<RefCell<Player>>` in the `HashMap`s because `Mutex<PlayerList>` requires it. I am not accessing players from the network thread (or any other thread) so it makes no sense to put them under a `Mutex`. Only the `HashMap`s need to be locked, which I am doing using `Mutex<PlayerList>`. But Rust is pedantic and wants to protect against all misuses.

As I'm only accessing `Player`s in the main thread, locking every time to do that is both annoying and less performant. Is there a workaround instead of using `unsafe` or something?

Here's an example:

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Uuid([u8; 16]);

struct Player {
    pub name: String,
    pub uuid: Uuid,
}

struct PlayerList {
    by_name: HashMap<String, Arc<Mutex<Player>>>,
    by_uuid: HashMap<Uuid, Arc<Mutex<Player>>>,
}

impl PlayerList {
    fn add_player(&mut self, p: Player) {
        let name = p.name.clone();
        let uuid = p.uuid;

        let p = Arc::new(Mutex::new(p));
        self.by_name.insert(name, Arc::clone(&p));
        self.by_uuid.insert(uuid, p);
    }
}

struct NetworkServer {
    player_list: Arc<Mutex<PlayerList>>,
}

impl NetworkServer {
    fn start(&mut self) {
        let player_list = Arc::clone(&self.player_list);
        thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                // fake network loop
                // listen for incoming connections, accept player and add them to player_list.
                player_list.lock().unwrap().add_player(Player {
                    name: "blahblah".into(),
                    uuid: Uuid([0; 16]),
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

struct Server {
    player_list: Arc<Mutex<PlayerList>>,
    network_server: NetworkServer,
}

impl Server {
    fn start(&mut self) {
        self.network_server.start();
        // main game loop
        loop {
            // I am only accessing players in this loop in this thread. (main thread)
            // so Mutex for individual player is not needed although rust requires it.
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let player_list = Arc::new(Mutex::new(PlayerList {
        by_name: HashMap::new(),
        by_uuid: HashMap::new(),
    }));
    let network_server = NetworkServer {
        player_list: Arc::clone(&player_list),
    };
    let mut server = Server {
        player_list,
        network_server,
    };
    server.start();
}
```

Comment: I'm curious if you can fabricate a minimal example that doesn't compile but you think its safe, sound, and should compile. Outside of my curiosity, that might also lead to better suggestions for workarounds.

Comment: OK, the more I re-read it the more sense your question makes as-written. The problem is that *you want* both shared ownership and interior mutability of the `Players` in your `HashMap`s *and you want* those HashMaps shared between threads, *but* `Rc<RefCell<T>>` isn't `Send`.

Comment: [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=75e144ecfb9b8a8bb44d41989aeb0d40&version=stable)'s an isolated working example. Yes, I do understand that Rust requires this for safety reasons. But in my case, I'm only accessing individual players in just one thread. So a Mutex<Player> seems wasteful here and only serves to satisfy Rust compiler :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As I'm only accessing `Players` in the main thread, locking everytime to do that is both annoying and less performant.

You mean, as right now you are only accessing `Players` in the main thread, but at any time later you may accidentally introduce an access to them in another thread?

From the point of view of the language, if you can get a reference to a value, you may use the value. Therefore, if multiple threads have a reference to a value, this value should be safe to use from multiple threads. There is no way to enforce, at compile-time, that a particular value, although accessible, is actually never used.

This raises the question, however:

*If the value is never used by a given thread, why does this thread have access to it in the first place?*

It seems to me that you have a *design* issue. If you can manage to redesign your program so that only the main thread has access to the `PlayerList`, then you will immediately be able to use `Rc<RefCell<...>>`.

For example, you could instead have the network thread send a message to the main thread announcing that a new player connected.

At the moment, you are "Communicating by Sharing", and you could shift toward "Sharing by Communicating" instead. The former usually has synchronization primitives (such as mutexes, atomics, ...) all over the place, and may face contention/dead-lock issues, while the latter usually has communication queues (channels) and requires an "asynchronous" style of programming.

Comment: But how would I do that? The network thread needs player list to add players to it :/

Comment: @WingerSendon: By sending a message from the network thread to the main thread, informing it that a new player connected? At the moment, you are "Communicating by Sharing", and you could shift toward "Sharing by Communicating" instead. The former usually has synchronization primitives (such as mutexes, atomics, ...) all over the place, and may face contention/dead-lock issues, while the latter usually has communication queues (channels) and requires an "asynchronous" style of programming.

Comment: Omg I was thinking about that just now. It's more intuitive and really solves this problem. Can you please edit your answer to add that as a workaround? I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @WingerSendon: Done :)

Comment: The later is often used on *nix with processes exchanging flat data (streams of octets) by local sockets and pipes. Careless programmers often produce deadlocks where two processes are stuck waiting for data from the other.

Comment: "_while the latter usually has communication queues (channels)_" you mean, like the **mutex_unlock** message sent to the communication channel of the **mutex_lock** threads? Or the **cv_signal** message sent on the **cv_wait** channel?

Answer (score 1):

`Send` is a marker trait that governs which objects can have ownership transferred across thread boundaries. It is automatically implemented for any type that is entirely composed of `Send` types. It is also an unsafe trait because manually implementing this trait can cause the compiler to not enforce the concurrency safety that we love about Rust.

The problem is that `Rc<RefCell<Player>>` isn't `Send` and thus your `PlayerList` isn't `Send` and thus can't be *sent* to another thread, even when wrapped in an `Arc<Mutex<>>`. The `unsafe` workaround would be to `unsafe impl Send` for your `PlayerList` struct.

Putting this code into your playground example allows it to compile the same way as the original with `Arc<Mutex<Player>>`

```
struct PlayerList {
    by_name: HashMap<String, Rc<RefCell<Player>>>,
    by_uuid: HashMap<Uuid, Rc<RefCell<Player>>>,
}

unsafe impl Send for PlayerList {}

impl PlayerList {
    fn add_player(&mut self, p: Player) {
        let name = p.name.clone();
        let uuid = p.uuid;

        let p = Rc::new(RefCell::new(p));
        self.by_name.insert(name, Rc::clone(&p));
        self.by_uuid.insert(uuid, p);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=efef1ddf0376f6ada2676fbbb0724d91&version=stable)

The [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html) is sadly a little sparse at explaining what rules have have to be enforced by the programmer when unsafely implementing `Send` for a type containing `Rc`s, but accessing in only one thread seems safe enough...

For completeness, [here's TRPL's bit on Send and Sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch16-04-extensible-concurrency-sync-and-send.html)

Comment: I think this answers the question. But I'm not sure if I'd actually have enough confidence or understanding of the consequences to actually implement it in production code.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to use unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest solving this threading problem using a multi-sender-single-receiver channel. The network threads get a `Sender<Player>` and no direct access to the player list.

The `Receiver<Player>` gets stored inside the `PlayerList`. The only thread accessing the `PlayerList` is the main thread, so you can remove the `Mutex` around it. Instead in the place where the main-thread used to lock the mutexit dequeue all pending players from the `Receiver<Player>`, wraps them in an `Rc<RefCell<>>` and adds them to the appropriate collections.

---

Though looking at the bigger designing, I wouldn't use a per-player thread in the first place. Instead I'd use some kind single threaded event-loop based design. (I didn't look into which Rust libraries are good in that area, but tokio seems popular)

Comment: Thank you. Using async sockets is in my TODO list. I'm just waiting for async-await to evolve a bit, since using future combinators is a bit awkward at the moment, to me at least.

Comment: @WingerSendon For a game, I'd prefer an event based design over async-await, even in languages where it's available. In the first iteration, you just have one place in the game loop where you dequeue all incoming messages. On the sending side you can use an infinite output buffer for the first iteration.

Comment: Rust uses an event loop based design for async-await though (readiness based design). So I think async-await can work well with it considering the fact that async-await is just syntax sugar for building the `Future` state machine.

Comment: @WingerSendon I'm talking about the style you write your own code in. Processing all incoming messages once per frame is a great fit for most games. I don't see how the sequential flow of async-await would be useful there.

Comment: I'm writing a game server and yeah I'm gonna be using channels to send messages from networking thread to main thread's loop. Async-await is for the socket processing as I don't want to be blocking if I don't want thread per player..